# Одинаковый SID в рабочей группе

Tags: windows, ntfs

Добрый день. Подскажите как легко и просто сделать на 5 ПК в рабочей группе одинаковый SID у группы пользователей. Вопрос связан с тем, что имеются носители информации, на них ограничены права записи с помощью NTFS для определенной группы. Что бы записать на другом ПК файлы нужно добавлять локальную группу на этом ПК. Группы созданы одинаковые на всех 5 ПК. Оказалось что бы была возможность иметь одинаковые разрешения то нужно иметь одинаковые SID на всех 5 ПК у всех этих групп.

Answer (score 1):

Это решается созданием контроллера домена, проверяющего и синхронизирующего эти права на разных носителях.

Comment: Раньше были эти ПК в домене. Мы их вывели. Поэтому вот и стоит задача как сделать это без домена.

Comment: Проясните ситуацию! Как вы их "вывели из домена"? Просто отключили, что ли? А права поправить чего не хватило?

Comment: Мы их просто вывели с домена. Как обычно выводят ПК из домена. (В свойстве моего компьютера изменили домен на рабочую группу) У нас права постоянно меняются на внешних носителях. Вот представьте себе такую ситуацию у вас есть 20 переносных HDD и 40 флешек которые подключаются к ПК. Подключаются всегда в разные ПК. Эти носители информации форматируются и на них пишется информация. После этого к примеру с ПК 1 на  ПК 2 мы переносим флешку и уже на втором ПК нужно добавлять текущего пользователя в группу безопасности на флешке.

Comment: ..продолжение...  Это очень не удобно. Я читал что если поменять SID, т.е. на всех ПК сделать его одинаковым то добавив пользователя на одном ПК он будет иметь такие же права как и на всех.

Comment: Так, давайте всё же разберёмся: SID - уникален для каждой учётной записи Windows. Это для безопасности. Как его изменить - вам тут никто не скажет. Потому, что! А вот если вам хватило ума включить в домен любой внешний носитель - так именно каждый придётся и выводить! По отдельности на каждом носителе!А то,  что вы имеете в  виду - это в локальной сети!

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы изменить СИДы локального юзера надо в реестре покапаться. Ветку не подскажу, но есть же Ctrl+F

Comment: Кажись там не все так просто. Меня интересует именно программа для этого дела.

Comment: Нет уж! Раз залез, то пусть помучается! Зато больше знаний будет!